# VSCode - Is there a way to "Open with VSCode" and open in a window / VSCode instance other than my project workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to "Open with VSCode" and open in a window or VSCode instance other than my project workspace?

I've usually got at least one VSCode instance going, open at workspace folder level, specific to the project I'm working on. If I want to open a one off file, I want it to open in a standalone window or VSCode instance or a window that I've previously opened other one off files (Not my workspace instances basically).

Because the current VSCode behaviour I'm still opening some files with Notepad++ just so that I don't pollute my workspace instances with lots of transient tabs.

[image: Open with VSCode]

Answer (score 0):

Found the setting I need, via this Github issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/48

Note that this causes a new window to be opened for every file, but this is manageable since it's easy to select from a view windows in the Windows task bar.

[image: VSCode open files in new window]